# Django website doesn't load some sections of website from some countries

Tags: python, django, web

Would anybody please help me with this strange situation? My website jehlum.org is working perfectly when browsed from Asia or Europe but when you try to browse it from US, the ads section (one of the 3 sections on homepage) disappears. I even tried changing vps provider but to no avail.
Any idea why is this happening? Had it been geographical kind of restriction on my domain then while website shouldn't load in browser, but this is something partial.

Regards/

Comment: `ads provider` may have some sort of restrictions on Asia or Europe, maybe GDPR issue?

Comment: No the ads are added by end users directly. Have a look at mentioned website @ruddra